# Finding Grayscale or Color images with Opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to automate and filter out grayscale & color images with the help of openCV python. I've tried to run histogram on color & grayscale images, find the result below

[image: GrayScale Vs Color Image]

### Tried Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
h = np.zeros((300,256,3))

bins = np.arange(256).reshape(256,1)
color = [ (255,0,0),(0,255,0),(0,0,255) ]
for ch, col in enumerate(color):
    hist_item = cv2.calcHist([img],[ch],None,[256],[0,256])
    cv2.normalize(hist_item,hist_item,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    hist=np.int32(np.around(hist_item))
    pts = np.column_stack((bins,hist))
    cv2.polylines(h,[pts],False,col)
h=np.flipud(h)
cv2.imshow('colorhist',h)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Can I automate the same without creating the histogram chart for each file?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the channel comparisons above, using numpy array slicing and assuming image is RGB or HSV like colorspace:

```
def isbw(img):
    #img is a numpy.ndarray, loaded using cv2.imread
    if len(img.shape) > 2:
        looks_like_rgbbw = not False in ((img[:,:,0:1] == img[:,:,1:2]) == (img[:,:,1:2] ==  img[:,:,2:3]))
        looks_like_hsvbw = not (True in (img[:,:,0:1] > 0) or True in (img[:,:,1:2] > 0))
        return looks_like_rgbbw or looks_like_hsvbw
    else:
        return True
```

Easy to expand to check other colorspace conditions.

Not extensively tested for 'edge/outlier' cases (e.g. other possible formats). Will fail for a red channel only (BGR) image as this will look like a black and white HSV image, so trusting to the cv2 cvtColor conversion to BGR format may be better depending on image subjects. Other 'edge' cases may exist.

Answer (score 1):

here is a sample c++ code to determine if the image is color or grayscale. i think you can easily convert it to python.

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "iostream"

using namespace cv;

bool isGrayImage( Mat img ) // returns true if the given 3 channel image is B = G = R
{
    Mat dst;
    Mat bgr[3];
    split( img, bgr );
    absdiff( bgr[0], bgr[1], dst );

    if(countNonZero( dst ))
        return false;

    absdiff( bgr[0], bgr[2], dst );
    return !countNonZero( dst );
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    static const char* str[] = {" is a COLOR image"," is a GRAY image"};
    char* filename = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : (char*)"fruits.jpg";
    Mat src = imread(filename);

    if(src.data)
    {
        std::cout << filename << str[isGrayImage( src )] << std::endl;
        imshow(filename, src );
        waitKey();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load image as color using `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR` (1) flag ([imread](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) documentation):

```
img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1], 1)
```

and then check if image has the same pixel values for red, green, blue channels for every pixel.

```
for x in range(0, width):
  for y in range(0, height):
    if img[x, y, 0] == img[x, y, 1] == img[x, y, 2]:
      # needs to be true for all pixels
    else:
      # not grayscale
```

You can also try to use [channels](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-channels) method when loading image using `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH` flag.

Comment: What is the value of  width and height?

Comment: Width and height of the image.

Comment: I've included `height,width,channel = img.shape` Now the program runs. But I get an "IndexError"